# Insert Row in SQL Server table then check row in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day everyone. As part of a much larger query to generate a large report, I have a scenario where if certain criteria are met, I assign a value to the field and go on to the next row. In this case I am talking about courses at a community college that meet the criteria for a First Level College Course (FCLC) in math or reading or writing.

The issue is, for each student, there can be more than one course in the reporting period that can qualify as FCLC, but we only need to report one of them as FCLC. Being a structured programmer from decades past, I could do it easy in PL/1 or C (yes that long ago) with variables but cannot get it working in SQL Server.

I have created temp database to hold the students, courses and FCLC value, but then I need to check that database in each of the subsequent runs thru the query.

Here is a pared down version of what I am trying to do. Any thoughts? My pride is not on the line so let me have it.

In this first snippet, I create the temporary table @FCLC_VALUES, and have the first CTE cte_course_data, which will get the Students ID, the course section number and course name. Output would look like this.

| PERSON_ID | COURSENAME |
| --- | --- |
| 0018738 | PHIL-2306 |
| 0018738 | PSYC-2314 |
| 0018937 | SPAN-1300 |
| 0019903 | GEOL-1401 |

```
    DECLARE @FCLC_VALUES TABLE (PERSON_ID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, COURSENAME VARCHAR(15), FCLC CHAR(1));
    WITH cte_course_data(PERSON_ID,COURSENAME)
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            ENR.SCS_STUDENT_ID
            ,CONCAT(rtrim(CRS.SUBJECT_ID),'-',rtrim(crs.COURSE_NO)) as coursename
        FROM            
            BSDW_2.DBO.RAD_ENROLLMENTS AS ENR
            INNER JOIN COLLIVE.DBO.STUDENT_COURSE_SEC AS SCS
            ON ENR.SECTION_ID = SCS.COURSE_SECTION_ID
            INNER JOIN COLLIVE.dbo.COURSE_SECTIONS AS CSECT
            ON CSECT.CRS_SEC_ID = SCS.COURSE_SECTION_ID 
            inner join COLLIVE.DBO.COURSES AS CRS
            ON CRS.COURSE_ID = CSECT.COURSE 
            LEFT JOIN COLLIVE.DBO.TX_ST_RPT_PARAMS_TASP_DEV_CRSS AS TXSTP
            ON
            CRS.COURSE_ID = TXSTP.DEV_EDUC_COURSES      
        WHERE   
       ((CSECT.STRT_DATE >= @BEGINDATE) AND (CSECT.STRT_DATE <= @CENSUS)AND 
       (CSECT.END_DATE <= @ENDDATE) and (CSECT.TERM_ID = @TERM))
    )
    ,
```

This next CTE takes the coursename and checks to see if it qualifies for First College Level Course status based on standards set by the state. Output would be like this.

| COURSE_NAME | COLLEGE_LVL_COURSE_AREAS |
| --- | --- |
| MATH-1314 | M |
| MATH-1316 | M |
| MATH-1324 | M |
| SPCH-2341 | R |
| TECA-1303 | R |
| TECA-1311 | R |
| ENGL-2323 | RW |
| ENGL-2326 | RW |

```
    cte_find_new_fcls (COURSENAME,FCL) AS
    (   
        SELECT
            CRSE.COURSE_NAME
            ,FCL.COLLEGE_LVL_COURSE_AREAS

        FROM            
            COLLIVE.dbo.COURSES AS CRSE
LEFT JOIN COLLIVE.dbo.TX_ST_RPT_PARAMS_TASP_COLL_CRSS as FCL 
            ON CRSE.COURSE_ID = FCL.TASP_COLLEGE_LVL_COURSES        
    )
```

This is the main code that joins the CTEs together and inserts the students ID, the course name and the new FCLC status into the table we created at the beginning. NOTE: Here is where I get stuck. The next time we go thru this code segment for the same student, I need to be able to search the @FCLC_VALUES table to see if we have already assigned the value such as ‘2’ for Reading to a previous course. Output from execution would look like this. Of particular note here are the first two entries with the same PERSON_ID. Only the first one should have an FCLC value of 2, because the query would check for this student in the @FCLC_VALUES table and see they already had a value of 2.

| PERSON_ID | COURSENAME | FCLC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0018738 | PHIL-2306 | 2 |
| 0018738 | PSYC-2314 | 2 |
| 0018937 | SPAN-1300 | 0 |
| 0019903 | GEOL-1401 | 0 |
| 0019984 | POFI-1104 | 0 |

```
    INSERT INTO @FCLC_VALUES (PERSON_ID,COURSENAME,FCLC)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CCD.PERSON_ID
            ,fcl.COURSENAME
            ,CASE   
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'M'  AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0') <> '1' THEN 
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'R' AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0')  NOT IN ('2','4') THEN '2'  
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'RW'  AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0')  NOT IN ('2','4')  THEN '2'
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'RW' AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0') NOT IN ('3','4') THEN 
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'W' AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0') NOT IN ('3','4') THEN 
                WHEN ISNULL(FCL.FCL,'0') = 'RW' AND ISNULL(FCLC.FCLC,'0') <> '4' THEN '4'                                               
                ELSE '0'
            END AS FCLC

        FROM
            cte_course_data as ccd
            LEFT join cte_find_new_fcls as fcl
            on fcl.COURSENAME = ccd.COURSENAME
            LEFT join 
            @FCLC_VALUES AS FCLC
            ON ccd.PERSON_ID = FCLC.PERSON_ID
```

Comment: Hard to say as you haven't properly described what you would like to do. It sounds like you might need a row numbering solution. Can you edit your post and explain in *plain english* what you would like to do, step by step. Please include sample data input and expected output

Comment: I can do that. I have pared down a much larger program so I was hoping I did enough but will go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I have edited the post and hopefully made it much easier to understand.

Comment: I was able to get past my issue and so far not even need the temp table, using windowing with the row numbering. A couple of my co-workers had to pound it into my head, but I get it now. Thanks for the help!!